# MAVEN , How can remove JSP page based on environment

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I am building one war file using `mvn clean install -Dlifecycle=dev` . so i have variable `lifecycle`.

Now my requirement is , when i create build file for `UAT/PROD` it must exclude one `jsp(index.jsp)` from package .My jsp is in webApps directory parallel to resources.

Using `profile` only for one page filtering is not good idea i think.

Appreciate any help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It starts with one JSP. Next is a customized CSS. Then different DB properties...

A profile is the way to go. Just create one, [set its activation to the value of the variable](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), create another source folder with the JSP and add it to the resources in the profile.

So:

- Create a folder `src/dev/webapp` in your project folder (so it is parallel to `src/main/webapp`)
- Add a profile to your `pom.xml` that configures the war plugin

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>lifecycle</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/dev/webapp</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This copies the resources from `src/dev/webapps` into the merged target folder when the variable `lifecycle` is set to `dev`.

Even if those are quite some lines of XML for copying a single file I think it is not a good idea to do it different (e.g. with a plugin that deletes files) when using Maven. While you can customize Maven builds so they aren't recognizable any more, the whole idea is to use the conventions so others can easily read the process.

Comment: Everything I am doing with plugin only.How can i do it with plugin . If you provide any sample ,will be helpful.